# Variables are not getting overwritten in media queries

Tags: sass

I need to changes values of few variable under media quires. Right not its not working. Is it possible?

```
$origami-width:             565px;
$origami-height:            332px;
    @media (max-width: $screen-sm-max){
    $origami-width:             370px;
    $origami-height:            300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made it working like this. Thanks!

```
 @media (min-width: $screen-md){
    $origami-width:             565px;
    $origami-height:            332px;

    .origami-container {
        width: $origami-width * 2;
    }
    .origami {
        @include size($origami-width, $origami-height);

        .content {
            height: $origami-height;
        }
    }
 }

 @media (max-width: $screen-sm-max){
    $origami-width:             370px;
    $origami-height:            300px;

    .origami-container {
        width: $origami-width * 2;
    }
    .origami {
        @include size($origami-width, $origami-height);

        .content {
            height: $origami-height;
        }
    }
}
```